# Determinant of $A_{n \times n}$ matrix where $a_{ij} = (b_{i} ^{2} - b_{j} ^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Determinant of $A_{n \times n}$ $n≥3$ matrix where $a_{ij} = (b_{i} ^{2} - b_{j} ^2)$ $i,j = 1,2,3,4....n$ for some distinct real numbers $b_{1}, b_{2},b_{3}....b_{n}$. Then what is det$|A|$ $?$

Clearly, this is a skew symmetric matrix, so determinant is $0$ when $n$ is odd. But I've no idea about its determinant when $n$ is even.

Any hint or idea to solve this problem$?$

Comment: Have you tried checking the results of a few small even values of $n$, e.g., $2$ and $4$, to see if there's any potential pattern? If you have tried them, if you didn't see anything useful, please update your question text to indicate what the results are. Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention $n≥3$

Comment: @Mathsaddict Yes, but reiterating John's question, did you actually check when n=4? If not, it might be insightful to see what happens if you try to compute the determinant through row reduction.  In particular, what is the difference between two rows?